# Linear regression in MATLAB and adding new features

Tags: matlab, regression, linear-regression

I'm using the [`regress`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html) function in MATLAB for multiple linear regression. Below is the sample code given by the `regress` documentation:

```
load carsmall
x1 = Weight;
x2 = Horsepower;    % Contains NaN data
y = MPG;

X = [ones(size(x1)) x1 x2 x1.*x2];
b = regress(y,X)    % Removes NaN data
```

I don't understand why they use `ones(size(x1))` and `x1.*x2` in the above code. Are these the first coefficient (beta zero) and epsilon value respectively of the model below?

```
yi = b0 +  b1*xi1 +  b2*xi2 + ... bp*xip +  ei for i = 1,2, ... n
```

If I have more than two features, for example `x1, x2, x3`, how can I change above formula to account for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each column of `X` is one feature.  Specifically, each column describes a value `xi` and one row describes a sample.  Specifically, each row has `n` features where each column describes a feature for that sample.

The reason why you make the first column all ones, is because this will allow you to have the intercept term in your model.  This allows you to have bias and is independent of any features you put in. It also seeks to help minimize error in prediction. In linear regression, you are correct in that you have a prediction model that is the sum of terms with weights.

Concretely, it should be

```
yi = b0*x0 + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + ...bi*xi + ... + bn*xn + ei, for i = 1, 2, ... n
```

`ei` is the error that is introduced for a sample to get the desired output.  Linear regression seeks to **minimize the error** introduced for each sample so that when you input in an unknown feature vector / sample, the output should give you a prediction with the least amount of error.  When using `regress`, you don't have access to this value, but be assured that it isn't needed and that this value is factored into the regression coefficients so that the least amount of error is produced when performing a prediction.

As you can see, when comparing with your equation, the model requires `x0` to be 1 to allow for `b0` to act as an intercept term, which is why you have the first column as all being ones.  Now, the reason why this is all "linear" is because even though one of your features is non-linear, the weights `bn` **are linear**.  Specifically, you have three features you are looking at:

```
x1 = Weight
x2 = Horsepower
x3 = x1*x2 --> Weight * Horsepower
```

The output will give you 4 linear regression coefficients (including the intercept term) that tell you how much weight each feature has when predicting an output.  If you want to add more features, you simply have to add more columns to `X` which will give you more coefficients that you use to can perform regression on test data.

For example, let's say you wanted to add two more features: `Cylinders` and `Displacement` in the matrix.

Therefore, all you'd have to do is:

```
load carsmall
x1 = Weight;
x2 = Horsepower;    % Contains NaN data
x3 = Cylinders; %// New
x4 = Displacement; %// New
y = MPG;

X = [ones(size(x1)) x1 x2 x1.*x2 x3 x4]; %// New
b = regress(y,X)    % Removes NaN data
```

`b` would contain coefficients that weight each feature so that you can use this to predict the MPG.  The more features you have, the more coefficients you have.  Be wary that introducing too many features may cause overfitting and will unfortunately give you bad accuracy on a test data sample.

There's a fine line between deciding which features you want to incorporate into your model and improving model prediction accuracy.

Comment: Thank you @rayryeng. So x1*x2 here is another feature, just like x1 and x2. Two last questions I want to ask:
1. Why don't we just use x1*x2? Why do we need a dot between them as x1.*x2?
2. What about epsilon value?

Comment: @ZCox - Correct.  `x1.*x2` is another feature that multiples weight and horsepower together.  It's almost similar to the Power-To-Weight Ratio that you see in measuring car performance.

Comment: @ZCox (1) You use `x1.*x2` because you are doing an element-wise multiplication.  You are taking all samples of `x1` that describe that feature and multiplying this vector element-wise with `x2` which is another vector.  Doing `x1*x2` is a matrix multiplication, and that's not what you want.

Comment: @ZCox (2) The epsilon is factored in to the regression coefficients.  What regression is doing here is that it is finding the coefficients that have **the least amount of error**.  Implicitly, `regress` is seeking to minimize `epsilon` for every sample in your data.  You don't have access to this, but be ensured that this is as small as can be.  The `epsilon` explains the error in prediction that the model does not account for.... linear regression is done by least squares, and it is well known that finding the regression coefficients attempts to minimize this error as much as possible.